# How to avoid this four-line memory leak with NumPy+MKL?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, numpy, intel-mkl

The following simple four-line code produces a memory leak in my Python 2.6.6 / NumPy 1.7.0 / MKL 10.3.6 setup:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.random.rand(10,10)
while True:
  t = t / np.trace(t)
```

With each operation, the used memory grows by the size of a 10x10 matrix. However, there is no such behaviour when I use a NumPy 1.4.1/ATLAS setup.

I have read about MKL not necessarily freeing memory automatically, so I guess this is the reason for the blowup. Is there a simple way to modify NumPy (before or after compilation), such that this four-liner will work fine?

Output of np.show_config()

```
numpy 1.7.0

lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$MKLPATH/include']
```

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug in numpy. Maybe you'll have more luck submitting to their bug tracker or trying numpy 1.8?

Comment: interestingly the effect still happens with `gc.collect` in the loop ([gc - garbage collection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html)) pointing to a numpy bug. Maybe worth raising on their issue tracker?

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted this issue to the numpy bug tracker. I will close this question as soon as I get a positive answer there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed a NumPy bug, which has been known for some months and has been discussed [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2969); it will be fixed in 1.7.1. The fix is [this nice one-liner in item_selection.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/80b3a3401382cb3f14c5b76dd90d9f932f50ad15). After adding this line and recompiling, everything works fine.